# C-panel version control unable to pull from GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, version-control, cpanel

Hi have a problem with my C-panel and GitHub account repository.

I have configured following things.

1. GitHub private repository
2. C-panel with Subdomain with hosting
3. C-panel Version control for private repository
4. SSH key in C-panel and generate public key and private key. Also authorized that key in C-panel SSH section
5. Put public key in private repository setting section deploy keys

[Deploy keys in GitHub image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsIbt.png)

When i try to hit "Update from Remote" in Git™ Version Control section (in Cpanel) that window shows "repository is up-to-date" alert, but i cannot see any newly updated activities in my host file folder.

[Git™ Version Control - Pull of Deploy Section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5U3m.png)

[Git™ Version Control - Basic Info Section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qGJQ.png)

It is only show initial git clone which i had made in first step. But i cannot fetch newly updated data from GitHub, What is i have missing here?

I have already put a file called '.cpanel.yml' file which had this configurations

```
---
deployment:
tasks:
   - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/mydomainpath
   - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

I saw this file also need to be in project folder in order to work with Cpanel and GitHub version control system. But nothing seems working.

(i have covered some of project info in images due to private details)

Much appreciate anybody can give me a favor in this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: anybody know a solution?